# Get the data, error information (including stack) and print outputs (including from third-party code) from the multiprocessed function

Tags: python, multiprocessing

When running functions in multiprocessing mode, the results of print statements, outputs of third-party libraries and so on are printed chaotically in the wrong order or even not printed at all due to the nature of multiprocessing.

I am trying to get all of the following:

- Print statements
- Output from any third-party libraries
- Error messages, including the stack (debugging the errors in multiprocessed function is very hard without it)
- The returned values

For now, I have come up with the following code to achieve that:

```py
import multiprocessing
import io
import contextlib
import traceback


def single_function(arg):
    buf = io.StringIO()
    with contextlib.redirect_stdout(buf), contextlib.redirect_stderr(buf):
        result = None
        try:
            result = 10 / arg  # Errors on arg == 0
            print("Successfully processed", arg)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error with the argument {arg}: {e}")
            traceback.print_tb(e.__traceback__)
        finally:
            return buf.getvalue(), result


def mass_function(numbers):
    with multiprocessing.Pool() as pool:
        results = pool.map(single_function, numbers)
    for result in results:
        print(f"Result: {result[1]}")
        print(result[0])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = [2, 1, 0] # Zero is added on purpose to demonstrate the error output
    mass_function(data)
```

Here is an output:

```
Result: 5.0
Successfully processed 2

Result: 10.0
Successfully processed 1

Result: None
Error with the argument 0: division by zero
  File "C:\Users\T1Ivan\Desktop\GitHub\human-robot\test.py", line 12, in single_function
    result = 10 / arg  # Errors on arg == 0
```

Is there a more pythonic/elegant and less verbose way to achieving that? Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Logging would be enough in a multi-threading environment, but in a multiprocessing context it could still produce strange behaviors. The main issue is to serialize/order the "prints" ... you could use a queue that you pass to each process, and have an extra process read from the queue and do the "real" print.

Comment: Thank you @LohmarASHAR! My solution prints all the outputs only when all the work is done. Are you suggesting using the pipe to get the print statements in real time?

Comment: It's a matter of choice, but yeah I like my output to be more realtime. I hate tools that take a lot of time to gather all the data and only in the end print something ... and I'm there _is it working ? is it stuck?_ ... _poke it with a stick_.

Comment: I haven't used pipes much (if at all) I see them more for a 1-on-1 bi-directional communication channels, usually I use queues ... each "sub process" becomes a "producer" (pushes data on the queue)  and the "logger" process  would play the role of the "consumer" it dequeues the data (messages in your case) and prints them 1 at a time

Comment: Thank you @LohmarAshar, I will research the use of queues for this. You are right that it is better to get the output, especially errors as soon as possible.